# Stutter with a moving platform using Tween movement

Tags: godot, gdscript

I'm having stuttering issues with a specific type of platform in my game, a vertical moving platform. Right now I'm moving it with a tween with the interpolate_property function, where the platform will tween itself from the position its currently at, and the next position is knows to go to. However I'm not quite sure if this is causing the issue, of if there is some deeper engine issue I'm not aware of.

Here is the line of code used for moving the platform:
the way it loops through all its checkpoints is by a signal of tween_completed

```
tween.interpolate_property(self, "position", self.position, nextCheckpoint, 
 speed,Tween.TRANS_LINEAR, Tween.EASE_IN_OUT)
```

video showing the bug
https://i.gyazo.com/f6b73ea763077e91917264d1188eaccf.mp4

Comment: What comes to mind is making sure the Tween process mode is set to physics.

Comment: Tried that, no change... Wish it was that simple though thanks for the reply!

Comment: I would try to increase the physics FPS in the project settings.